# How to efficiently select NON-NULL, NON-EMPTY rows based off multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query below works, however I am wondering if there is a way to optimize it? As it stands now it will be doing multiple table scans per OR statement?

The reason I am being defensive within the query is that if someone passes NULL or an empty string in the #{phone} or #{email} it will delete a lot of data further down the process. So its imperative to ONLY select strongly matching values for each OR statement.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM...

    WHERE (phone != '' AND phone IS NOT NULL AND phone = #{phone})

    OR (phone2 != '' AND phone2 IS NOT NULL AND phone2 = #{phone})

    OR (phone3 != '' AND phone3 IS NOT NULL AND phone3 = #{phone})

    OR (email != '' AND email IS NOT NULL AND email = #{email})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parameter `phone` should be sanitized in the application layer instead of the database.

However, if it's that critical as you mention, sometimes it's convenient to put some safety measures in place, like the ones you are using. If this is case, the query looks good.

From the point of view of performance the query can benefit from the indexes:

```
create index ix1 on t (phone);

create index ix2 on t (phone2);

create index ix3 on t (phone3);

create index ix4 on t (email);
```

Now, depending on the optimization and data histogram the engine may choose to avoid the indexes. If that's the case, you can promote the use of the indexes above by rephrasing your query using `UNION` instead of `OR` (old trick). For example:

```
SELECT ID 
WHERE (phone != '' AND phone IS NOT NULL AND phone = #{phone})
FROM...
UNION
SELECT ID 
WHERE (phone2 != '' AND phone2 IS NOT NULL AND phone2 = #{phone})
FROM...
UNION
SELECT ID 
WHERE (phone3 != '' AND phone3 IS NOT NULL AND phone3 = #{phone})
FROM...
UNION
SELECT ID 
WHERE (email != '' AND email IS NOT NULL AND email = #{email})
```

It's a lot easier for the engine to use the index when there are no `OR`s in the predicate. However, this trick pays the price later when performing the `UNION`s. If the number of selected rows is low, this cost should be marginal.